# Including <script> tag in <script type="text/template"> tag

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I am a new programmer and I have a little question. This is a part of my code:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><input type="button" value="HomePage" id="home1" data-page="home"></li>
     <li><input type="button" value="About" id="about1" data-page="about"></li>
   </ul>
</nav>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="page active">
            <div class=firstLoad>
            (some content...)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/template" id="home">
<div id="backImage">
  <div id="spinner">
</div>
<div>
   <input type="button" value="..." id="car" class="button">
</div>
<div>
   <input type="button" value="..." id="Car1" onclick="location.href='#'" class="button">
</div>
<div>
   <input type="button" value="..." id="reset" class="button">
</div>
</div>
<script src="location.js"></script>
</script>
```

My question is how can I use this "location.js" script tag in the html page (id="home") when I call this html page with innerHTML and I change the current appear page?
No matter what I have done this script doesn't work for me at all in the html page.

Thank you...:)

Comment: pls provide location.js script

Comment: You can't do it that way - it depends on your template system but somehow you have to "protect" the `</script>` tag in the template. Generally it's pretty questionable to import a script from inside a template however.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You have divs and a script tag nested inside of a script tag, which is probably invalid markup and makes no sense to me.

Comment: You'd need to dynamically reload your JS file

Comment: Also: adding the script tag when you update `innerHTML` won't load it anyway - you have to do that yourself.  (That's one of the reasons it's a questionable practice; there's almost certainly a better way to get the job done, whatever the job is.)

Comment: i am talking about any script. even script like this:
<script>
alert('hi');
</script>

like i said i am a new programmer and i dont really know how to do it...:)

my point is that now when i am opening the page i am in 1.html and when i clicking home button for example it transmmit me to page home.html

now the page loads perfect but the script in the page ("location.js") doesnt work at all.

how can i make it work in home.html?

Aaron Kurtzhals i am sorry, like i said i didnt know i cant put a script tag nested inside of a script tag.
because of that i am asking my question.
how can it work?

Comment: Dan Lee if you can show in short how i dynamically reload my JS file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not going to work for you. Not only is it invalid to have a `<script></script>` inside of another `<script>`, it wouldn't work even if the browser could parse it correctly. However, all you need to do is provide the javascript files you want to load in another manner, like in a `dataset` attribute. *Additionally, as Quentin pointed out, `text/template` isn't a standard type, so prefix it with `x-` as standard practice*

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="home" data-jsassets="location.js,/path/to/some/other.js">
   ...
</script>
```

Now, retrieve the comma-delimted list of javascript to load and inject it into the page, which will run the script:

```
var tpl, jsassets, tag, i,l;
tpl = document.getElementById('home');
// At this point, ensure your template has been rendered and attached to the page
// by your template processor
jsassets = (tpl.getAttribute('data-jsassets') || '').split(',');
for(i = 0, l = jsassets.length; i < l; i++){
  tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.type = "text/javascript";
  tag.src = jsassets[i];
  document.head.appendChild(tag);
}
```

Comment: rgthree
thank you so much!!!
i am lokking for this solution for 3 days!

just one more question, if i want to load to id="home" page more than one script what do i need to do in:
<script type="text/x-template" id="home" data-jsassets="location.js,/path/to/some/other.js">
   ...
</script>

i mean if i want "location.js" and "location1.js" to be load?

Comment: Yup, I've set that up for you. The `data-jsassets` attribute is setup as a comma-delimited list of the paths to load. So, you would have `data-jsassets="location.js,location1.js"` there to load those two files. Feel free to accept my answer if it's what you were looking for ;)

Answer (score 4):

HTML provides no means to include the sequence `</script>` inside a script element.

XHTML allows you to use CDATA markers or entities, but that isn't an option for HTML. (Note that XHTML served as text/html does not provide this option and browsers will use an HTML parser).

The language used inside the script needs to provide a mechanism to avoid the problem.

In JavaScript, for instance, `/` and `\/` mean the same thing inside a string, so you can `"<\/script>"`.

`text/template` isn't a standard MIME type. Presumably it is a custom template format used by some JS on the page. That JS would need to support some form of escaping mechanism when it is parsing the template. You may have to extend whatever library you are using to process your template.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but that isn't how the syntax works. Your `<script type="text/template">`

is only for html.

put the script with your logic outside of the template tag and you'll be working smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your template in  `<template>` tag.

```
<template id="home">
   <script></script>
</template>
```

Comment: Please stop suggesting this until you have a better understanding of the role of the template tag, how it differs from text/template script tags, and its limited browser support.