# Store HTML templates in HTML

Tags: html, mustache, html-templates

I need to store HTML templates to use them for Mustache rendering.

```
<!-- Templates. -->
<span style="display:none">

<span id="tplCard">
    {{#.}}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="caption">
            <p>{{caption}}</p>
            <button title="Edit" class="toolbar edit"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/.}}
</span>

<span id="tplRow">
    {{#.}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{caption}}</td>
        <td>{{text}}</td>
        <td>{{image}}</td>
        <td>
            <button>Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/.}}
</span>

</span>
<!-- End of templates. -->
```

Here is the using:

```
function FillWithData(container, template, data)
{
    var tpl = $('#' + template).html();
    var html = Mustache.render(tpl, data);
    $('#' + container).append(html);
}
```

The first template works, but the second one doesn't. Well, the problem is a `<TR>` is not a valid child for a `<SPAN>`, so the browser gets rid of them. How to store a random template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store the template data in a `script` tag. this will prevent the browser from parsing it as html. But you need to keep in mind that your template cannot contain `script` tags itself ([Including <script> tag in <script type="text/template"> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261232/including-script-tag-in-script-type-text-template-tag)). (this works with `<!doctype html>` but honestly i can't say for sure if it would work that way cross browser for other doctypes)

you would not need to change much in your setup:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="tplCard">
    {{#.}}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="caption">
            <p>{{caption}}</p>
            <button title="Edit" class="toolbar edit"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/.}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="tplRow">
    {{#.}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{caption}}</td>
        <td>{{text}}</td>
        <td>{{image}}</td>
        <td>
            <button>Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/.}}
</script>
```

`type="text/x-template"`  is used so that the browser would not try to execute it as a script.

**JS**

```
function FillWithData(container, template, data)
{
    var tpl = $('#' + template).text()||$('#' + template).html();
    var html = Mustache.render(tpl, data);
    $('#' + container).append(html);
}
```

the `$('#' + template).text()||$('#' + template).html()` is required because in some browser versions you need to use `.text()` and in the other you need to use `.html()` to get the content of the `script` tag.