# Javascript inside a Angular router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have build a very basic Angular Router. But now that I want to interact with my elements inside that templateUrl, no javascript gets executed or those elements inside the templateUrl can not be accessed. I have copied the most of the code from this instruction, [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating).

My index file:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head></head>

    <body ng-controller="mainController">

         <a id="btnHome" href="#/">Startseite</a>
         <a id="btnPlanner" href="#/planner">LTC-Planner</a>
         <a id="btnSocial" href="#/social">LTC-Social</a>

         <div id="main">
              <!-- angular content -->
              <div ng-view></div>
         </div>

         <script src="js/routing.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is my routing.js file:

```
// Create the angular module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

// Configure our routes
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider

   // Route for the home page
   .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
   });
});

// Create the controller and inject angular's $scope
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is the HOME page';
});
```

and this is the template file located at **pages/home.html**:

```
<button id="btnTest">Say Hello</button>

<script>
    var btnTest = document.getElementById('btnTest');

    btnTest.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('Hello'); 
    });
</script>
```

maybe one of you got an idea or has seen an alternative.

Thanks, 
André

Comment: can you also post your code where your angular app is bootstraped ? and maybe a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including <script> tag in <script type="text/template"> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261232/including-script-tag-in-script-type-text-template-tag)

Comment: Thanks for all your quick answers. 

@dfsq What would be your approach of creating a page router? Compared to React or Polymer or a server side router this method seemed to be very simple.

Comment: @WilliPasternak This is not my page, but it works the same: http://embed.plnkr.co/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try to wrap your html template in a single tag

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="test()">Say Hello</button>
</div>
```

And remove the script to put the logic inside your controller. Since your using angular, just use ng-click to bind click listener.

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is the HOME page';
    $scope.test = function() {
      console.log('Hello');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gatsbill.
dfsq criticized my way of creating a router. What would have been your approche?

Comment: With angular you can use ngRouter like you do or use ui-router but anyway both are usable. Dunno what was his point